# What does it mean by Vidura entering Yudhishthira’ body?

Tags: mahabharata

As explained in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32874/8735) answer, Vidura left his mortal body and entered  Yudhishthira’s

> Possessed of great intelligence, he then (by his Yoga-power) entered
>   the body of Yudhishthira, limb by limb. He united his life-breaths
>   with the king's life-breaths, and his senses with the king's senses.
>   Verify, with the aid of Yoga-power, Vidura, blazing with energy, thus
>   entered the body of king Yudhishthira the just.

What does this exactly mean? Does this mean his soul or subtle body will dwell inside  Yudhishthira? Also does that mean Vidura did not immediately go to heaven?

Comment: Your answer is this question..
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16905/irawati-karve-says-vidura-is-the-biological-father-of-yudhiṣṭhira-is-she-righ

Answer (score 1):

If we view their relationship as Guru and Disciple, then we will get different idea. It is a well known fact that a teacher will develop affection towards some students only, mainly due to their grasping power of the subject.

Vidura was known to be embodiment of Dharma. Out of 5 Pandavas and 100 Kauravas, he had shown affection towards Yudhisthira only, because the latter also embodiment of Dharma.

We have to remember that it was Vidura, who cautioned only Yuddhisthira in [Lakshagriha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakshagriha) episode.  Vidura was the Guru and Yudhisthira was his disciple.

That's why Vidura **transmitted** his SPIRITUAL energy to Yidhisthira in his last moments.

We should also remember that it was Yidhisthira alone went up to the pinnacle of Himayala during [mahaprasthAna](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m17/m17003.htm).

---

We will come across cases of Guru transmitting his energy to his disciple just before the death of the former.

The following is from the life history of [Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/introduction/last_days.htm).

> In last days before Sri Ramakrishna's departure, Narendra being alone
>   with the Master, Sri Ramakrishna looked at him and went into samadhi.
>   ***Narendra felt the penetration of a subtle force*** and lost all outer
>   consciousness. Regaining presently the normal mood, he found the
>   Master weeping.
>
> Sri Ramakrishna said to him: "Today I have given you my all and I am
>   now only a poor fakir, possessing nothing. By this power you will do
>   immense good in the world, and not until it is accomplished will you
>   return." Henceforth the Master lived in the disciple.