# Why do Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva always meditate on each other?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, worship

I watched a TV serial named "Devo ke Dev Mahadev" on channel "Life Ok". In that, they mentioned several stories of Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu always meditating upon each other and connected to each other at all times.

Is that true? If yes, what is the reason behind this? Can anybody enlighten me on this?

Comment: in my opinion, they meditate on each other just to show to everyone that both are one and the same God in two different forms! :)

Comment: @Sai, as you say that both are one and forms of same God, then why the God is meditate himself in different form?

Comment: good question! I think this would require a chat, because this would be dealing with a series of questions such as: What is meditation? Why should God meditate? Why would God meditate himself in different forms? etc. Because the answer to this would be simply straying off this question :). We can discuss this in chat.

Comment: Whether or not they are different forms of one God will actually vary depending on what kind of Hindu you ask. A Vaishnavite for instance would disagree that Vishnu is a form of Shiva.

Comment: Also, I can't remember where exactly but I think there was some discussion a while back on Vishnu's avatars meditating on Vishnu that might be relevant.

Comment: @Akshay Yes well said and thanks for clarifying! those who subscribe to advaita usually are of the belief in Oneness of God. Whereas those who subscribe to dvaita are of the belief in Multiplicity of God. And even among advaitists there are various categories, some who believe in vishistadvaita and some in achintyabhedabheda :). It is said "Infinite are the Leelas of God, infinite are His forms, Infinite are his powers and Infinite are the ways to reach Him". Dvaita and Advaita are not that different so long as there is sincere yearning in the devotee :)

Comment: Vishnu is the guru of Shiva, and Shiva is the guru of Vishnu. Hence they both meditate on their guru.

Comment: It's series and not serial.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would try to correct a one misconception that Lord Vishnu meditates on Lord Shiva. ***No he doesn't, Lord Vishnu actually meditates on Lord Brahma.***

It is a cyclic process, Lord Brahma meditates on Lord Shiva, Lord Shiva meditates on Lord Vishnu and Lord Vishnu meditates on Lord Brahma, and the cycle goes on.

**Why this Cycle ?**
Brahma is a creator by nature, but before creation there is destruction, so he needs to understand the destruction, therefore he meditates on Lord Shiva, Vishnu is a Preserver, to Preserve he needs to understand the generation(creation), therefore he meditates on Lord Brahma , Shiva on the other-hand is a  annihilator, to destroy he needs to understand Preservation, therefore he meditates on Lord Vishnu.

**Why they need to understand their predecessor process ?**
Natural law, every process is the outcome of a process, and to understand a process, you need to know origin process. This also shows the *cyclic and infinitum* nature of any process's existence. This is a reason why science went way back to atoms, then to neutrons and still searching the cause of it(currently medalling with string theory).

To make everything more visible, I created this image which conveys it all. In the image, B = Brahma, V = Vishnu and S = Shiva.

> [image]

**But is it not written in Puranas ?** Yes its written, but in other way, puranas say :

> Lord Vishnu worships Lord Shiva and Lord Shiva worships Lord Raam (Vishnu Avatar).

But meditation is different than worshiping. [Lord Shiva cursed Lord Brahma that he would not be worshiped by anyone.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/264/why-are-temples-devoted-to-brahma-so-rare/2317#2317) Meditation is needed to understand something, you want to understand 'BIKE' meditate on it, you want to understand 'GOD' meditate on him. Worshiping is kind of give-take relationship between Purusha and Prakrati, the prakrati worships Purusha, to get something from it. Some worship Purusha to easily understand the way(the creation or the God), because meditating can sometime become tougher and time lengthy and needs higher consciousness.

**About the Serial ?**

TV serial "Devo ke Dev Mahadev" on channel "Life Ok", also told the same thing, that ***Vishnu actually meditates on Bhrama***, It is in [8th October 2012, 234th episode.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rsx_8g4hY08)

The scene describes that Mata Parvati comes across Lord Shiva, who is meditating on Lord Vishnu at that time, she asks him the question why he meditating on Lord Vishnu, and their he answers about the cycle process.

Comment: Awesome knowledge Mr. K. Thanks for describing the process. Eventually i was missed that episode so didn't get around on it. Thanks!

Comment: @Anurag, i will still link it, as I remember less, but you will also love what the serial has to say about it.

Comment: You should cite sources.  Also, you shouldn't use block quotes unless you're quoting something.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, i'll remove blocks, secondly I wrote I will be adding a link, let me find one out.

Comment: @Anurag, added a link, do watch the episode.

Comment: Good reply Mr. K, I like your logic, but please donot use TV serial for the source of information and specially DKDM, it is way too far from the facts as described in the books in many cases. This particular TV serial uses too much of creativity and self written stories. However, i'll still say, I like your logic.

Comment: @Aby, thanks but the question was asked from that serial as a source itself, that's y I quoted its reference underneath. THANKS again.

Answer (score 7):

No one knows anything. The devotees of Vishnu say Lord Shiva meditates upon him, the devotees of Mata Shakti (Aadishakti) say he meditates on her. Different people have different opinions because no one wants to see their favourite deity look small in front of other but the truth is he doesn't meditate upon any other deity.

Who says meditation is only done upon somebody? No it's not. Some people who are atheistic also meditate. They don't meditate upon anyone. As you know there are three primary deities: Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh. Do you know why Shiva is called 'Mahesh'? What does it mean? 'Maha' + 'Ish' means Mahan Ishwar or you could say '*sabse bade* Ishwar', above whom there is nothing, beyond whom there is nothing.

There's an order of power. From all deities to King of deities Devraj Indra. If he couldn't handle anything they go to Lord Brahma and if he can't handle something, he refers them to Lord Vishnu and if the problem still seems uncontrollable, they are referred to the Supreme God; The one who is Mahadev (Devo ke Dev). Whom all worship, humans, deities, even demons and ghosts: Lord Shiva.

And the question why he meditates? Whom upon he meditates? Answer is NO ONE.

He doesn't need to meditate upon anyone. He is the Supreme Soul. Aadi Shakti is his powers he is the controller. He meditates to control Yuga. He meditates to create situations and meaningful examples for our life like Ram and Ravan, Maa Durga and Shumb Nishumb etc. Every situation what happened what we read in Puranas and Upanishads was created by him only to give us a hidden message. He meditates to control the whole Universe and that is from within only. Whatever we see is him only and whatever that doesn't exist is also in him only. When there was nothing, it was him only. And when there will be nothing, only he will be present there. He is *anadi*, he is *anant*.

All deities even Lord Vishnu also worships him in all his avatars. And that is not hidden, all know Rama was Shiva bhakth, Parashuram was Shiva bhakth and even Krishna got boon of sons from him. He is beyond time cycle and everything he never takes birth like other Lords and there is a misunderstanding that Hanuman was his avatar. No he wasn't. He was his Ansh avatar not him. Now many would say Krishna said he is the supreme one in Gita. If you see what Gita is all about what Lord Krishna was trying to tell, you will see it's "atma" which is the supreme soul. What can't be killed what does not take birth. Because we all atma's are a part of parmatma. He gave knowledge of atma, knowledge of Gita on supreme soul's behalf..because he himself is a part of him.

And yes now some of you must be thinking if Lord Shiva is the supreme power than why he needed Lord Vishnu to save his life from Bhasmasur I know some must be thinking. But no one knows about this incident exactly. The boon was given to him of burning anyone instantly if he puts his hand on that person's head. If Shiva wanted to kill him himself couldn't he kill by his trident (trishul) without letting him put his hand on his head? If Vishnu wanted to kill Bhasmasur couldn't he kill him by his disc (Sudarshan Chakra)? He could. They could. But still they didn't. Why? Have anyone of you try to understand why they didn't they kill him by their weapons? Why by dancing move? Let me tell you why. Because whatever happens has a hidden message behind it. And in that case this incident took place to show all of us an example that same boon (*vardhan*) what we ask for and try to misuse after getting can turn into curse (*shrap*) that was an example for all of us. We are very small creatures with too small minds to understand his leela.

I'm requesting to you all worship who you want to pray to Shiva, Krishna or Rama or anyone just don't try to show your favorite deity superior to Lord Shiva. Because your favorite deity themselves don't like it that you are insulting the one who they themselves worship. No matter which God you worship, you worship him only you can worship to yourself also because you are also a part of him. You are not distinct. It's written in Vedas: Shivoham (I am Shiva) Aham Bharmasami (*mein hi param brahma hu*).

Comment: You should cite some sources.

Answer (score 6):

In [Skanda Upanishad](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/skandaupan.html?lang=sa), we find the following verses:

> शिवाय विष्णु रूपाय शिव रूपाय विष्णवे |
>  **शिवस्य हृदयं विष्णुं
>   विष्णोश्च हृदयं शिवः** ||
>   यथा शिवमयो विष्णुरेवं विष्णुमयः शिवः
>   |
>  यथाsन्तरम् न पश्यामि तथा में स्वस्तिरायुषि|
>  यथाsन्तरं न भेदा:
>   स्यु: शिवराघवयोस्तथा||

Quoting the translation from [here](http://www.advaita.it/library/skandhaup.htm):

> 8-9. (I bow) to Shiva of the form of Vishnu and Vishnu who is Shiva;
>   **Vishnu is Shiva’s heart and Shiva, Vishnu’s.** Just as Vishnu is full of Shiva, so is Shiva full of Vishnu. As I see no difference, I
>   am well all my life.

Now, one always think upon what's in their hearts because that's very dear to them.

So, these verses might have inspired the serial makers in showing Shiva and Vishnu as always meditating upon each other.

(NOTE - Skanda Upanishad is one of the 108 Upnaishads and is a minor Upanishad. It is linked to the Krishna Yajurveda.)

Answer (score 1):

Lord Shiva stays in samadhi state and not in any meditative mode, the traditional shaivite scholars including some of the great Vedantic Advaitins see Lord Shiva as the state of "Turiyam" i.e the forth state which is pure consciousness (Shudda Chethana).

Whereas Lord Vishnu worshipping his Lord for Sudarshana chakra is evident from Hari vamsha parva of mahabharata.

> यत्र लेभे हरिश्चक्रमुपास्य बहुभिर्दिनैः ।
>
> पुष्करैः शतपत्रैश्च नेत्रेण च जगत्पतिम् ॥ 3.84.11
>
> That place where (Kailash) Hari obtained the Chakra by worshiping for several days the Jagatpati (Shiva), by lotus flowers and by his eye.

**-- Hari Vamsha Parva 3.84.11 [Mahabharata]**

Lord Vishnu along with Brahma being eternal subservient and devotee of Parameshvara Shiva is extremely evident from traditional Upanishads too which are quoted by Advaitins (prior to 12th century too).

> “sarvakaraNAni manasi saMpratiShThApya dhyAnan viShNuH prANaM manasi saha karaNaiH saMpratiShThApya dhyAtA rudraH prANaM manasi sahakaraNairnAdAnte paramAtmani saMpratiShThApya dhyAyIteshAnaM pradhyAyitavya.n sarvamidaM |”
>
> “The pranava (the sound of Om) makes all the souls to bow before it. It is the one and only one which has to be meditated upon as the four Vedas and the birth place of all devas. One who meditates like that goes away from all sorrows and fears and gets the power to protect all others who approach him. **It is because of this meditation only that Lord Vishnu who is spread every where, wins over all others**. It is because Lord Brahma controlled all his organs and meditated upon it, he attained the position of the creator. **Even Lord Vishnu , parks his mind in the sound (Om) of the place of Paramathma (ultimate soul) and meditates upon Ishana,** who is most proper to be worshipped. All this is only proper in case of Ishana”.

-- **Atharvarshika Upanishad 2.1**

Atharvarshika Upanishad being one among the significant upanishads is also quoted extensively by many of the traditional commentators. Acharya Amalananda (12th Century) an Advaita Vedantin writes a separate deepika on Atharvarshika Upanishad to glorify Lord Parameshvara Shiva in Advaitic mode.

Considering principle Upanishads like Kaivalya Upanishad, Shvetashvatara Upanishad, Jabala Upanishad and Maitri Upanishads which have been quoted by first ever legendary vedantic titan Adi Shankaracharya, Advaitic interpretations conclude Lord Shiva to be the absolute representation of the 'Nirguna Brahman' talked in Upanishads whereas Lord Vishnu is significant only in the mode of bhakti.

Hence, according to pure shastras Lord Vishnu is eternal devotee of Shiva whereas Lord Shiva is never depicted as someone who behaves like devotee.

Note:- None of the puranic or mythological scriptures can be considered to know about this topic as they are unequivocally sectarian.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Prabhas Kshetra Mahatmya of the Skanda Puran](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626812.html) both Lord Vishnu and Shiva do meditate on each other:

> Hari and I are apparently different. The reason thereof is the difference of the Guṇa. **In fact we are non-different. This is the greatest secret.The difference due to being the adored and the adorer is common to both of us.**

> For, I bear on my head devoutly this Gaṅgā that has issued forth from the tip of Viṣṇu’s foot despite the fact that I have been viewed with suspicion by you. Further, for the sake of protecting the three worlds, Viṣṇu adored me for a long time systematically and obtained the discus that kills the evil ones.

> You are the Mahāmāyā of Hari of incomprehensible nature. Out of devotion to him, I propitiate that Mahāmāyā, the cause of the origin of the three worlds. Similarly Hari also has another Śakti of mine placed on his head.

> Though he is unborn, he resorts to births and carries out the protection of the world. In order to kill Hiraṇyakaśipu he adopted the form of the Man-lion. When he (Viṣṇu as Man-Lion) was about to destroy the universe, I adopted the form of the (fabulous lion-killer) Śarabha and subdued him. In my attempt to save Bāṇa I raised my trident aloft. But even in his human incarnation, he could sportively stun me then.

> **Further, increasing my prowess and greatness he adores me daily, although the Lord is my immanent soul. Moreover, I always meditate on him, the Supreme Soul, devoid of beginning and end, by means of Dhyānayoga.**

> Therefore, there is no real difference between us. Difference and comparison are resorted to by deluded persons alone.

So there is no cycle involving the worship of Brahma it is a mutual respect that is shown by Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the instructions given by Bhagawan Shiva to them.

**Sri Shiva Purana 2.1:1:10.:**

> ***Lord Śiva said:—***
>
> *1. O Viṣṇu of good rites, O Hari, listen to another pronouncement of mine. You will be worthy of honour and worship in all the worlds for ever.*
>
> *2. Whenever a misery befalls the world created by Brahmā, you shall be eager for the destruction of all miseries.*
>
> *3. In all difficult and unbearable activities I shall help you. I shall kill your indefatigable and fierce enemies.*
>
> *4. O Viṣṇu, spread your glory in the worlds far and wide by taking up various incarnations. Strive for their succour. I am always Saguṇa when I become Rudra with this body.*
>
> *5. Certainly I shall perform your activities for the sake of the worlds if they are impossible for you.*
>
> ***6. You are to be meditated upon by Rudra and Rudra is to be meditated upon by you. There is no difference between you and Rudra.***

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..