# What does Lord Shiva think of during meditation? Also, did He ever fall prey to pride?

Tags: shiva, meditation

As we hear in Hindu mythology, most of the lords have fallen prey to pride and at last regretted heavily. Did Lord Shiva ever fall prey to pride?

And what does Lord Shiva think about during meditation, because during meditation we think about god and He is the god Himself?

Comment: Lord Shiva is the best medicine for false ego and pride.He always destroys it.He destroyed pride of ganapaty of surya of agni of yama of kamadeva and of ravana too."Ravana darpa vinasana Lingam"-from linga ashtakam.

Comment: Ohh ravana's pride was destroyed by shiva itself...i guess when he went to pick up the kailash mountain?? Is it??

Comment: Yes it was then only.And after that ravana composed and sung the Shiva Tandava Stotram.

Comment: Meditation is focusing your mind on a fixed point and that point not always has to be God.Although all yogis aiming for moksha focuses their mind on Parameswara himself but can we be sure what Lord himself thinks during meditating?.Btw, i might be right in guessing to which direction your question is going.Then let me tell you that Lord Vishnu also meditates upon Lord Shiva during his Yoga Nidras.

Comment: Am i asking right thing...bcoz shiva is is lord of yoga...or adiyogi i guess...so wat does he thinks of during meditation?? Is it jst lord vishnu

Comment: As a devotee i should not be too much bothered about that.Thats the most i can say.

Comment: Sir does it mean it has no answer??

Comment: In Shiva's heart lives Sri Vishnu and in Sri Vishnu's heart  lives Lord Shiva.Therein lies the answer.(And pls don't call me sir.)

Comment: @sachin  see [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3191/3500) question. You need to note a subtle difference here. Lord Rudra is human aspect and Lord Shiva or Parameswara is Brahman. So, Rudra is destructive aspect of Supreme Shiva. Rudra mediates on Vishnu.

Comment: Thats pretty worth a great applause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s very interesting, one day in Kailash, Goddess Parvati was looking a little bit bored because Shiva was just sitting there in deep, deep meditation. And she called, “Oh Lord.” And Shiva didn’t respond.

Goddess Parvati just stood there watching him for a long, long time. And ultimately when Lord Shiva opened his eyes, Goddess Parvati bowed down with devotion to the Lord. And she asked surprisingly, “My Lord, I have a question. The whole world meditates upon you, everyone is praying to you, meditating upon you, contemplating you, upon whom are you meditating?”

And Lord Shiva replied with a smile, “I always meditate on Rama. Rama is always in my heart" and with the happy face he continued, "Lord Vishnu is going to take Rama avatar with Goddess Lakshmi and I will serve them with Hanuman".

(This conversation happened before Rama avatar of Lord Vishnu)

From this conversation, it is clear that Lord Shiva mediates on Lord Rama. It is not only because of Lord Rama,the avatar of Lord Vishnu. Lord Shiva always have pure love on Lord Rama and so he give Lord Rama such a holy place in his heart.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: I got so many answers...im proud to say that my doubt has been completely cleared...just that shiva and vishnu...both treat each other as their gods??

Comment: I downvoted your answer. I CAN go and search many texts in which Shiva himself meditate on his own Shakti, energising her. And those sources fall in the emphasiz: Shiva always keep in mind Iisus, for example. It is clear now, why I donwvoted. To favorise one cult against others is such a bad practice. If we admit Shiva as Supreme, I think is obvious we can not understand, with our mind, what and how Supreme thinks if He thinks. Don't judge God from your limited mind and don't ask how and what He does. Search to emerge in Him. That is a better way to understand your own mind limits.

Comment: Hi user3344236. This site is for sharing the resources from our precedence and try to analysis that. It is apart from personal reasons. I just shared what I was answered for the above question with site source.

Answer (score 2):

Lord Shiva meditates in Nirvikalp Samadhi(breathless and thoughtless state).

> Samādhi (Sanskrit: समाधि, Hindi pronunciation: [səˈmaːd̪ʱi])
>   schools refers to a state of meditative consciousness. It is a
>   meditative absorption or trance, attained by the practice of
>   dhyāna. In samādhi the mind becomes still. It is a state of being
>   totally aware of the present moment; a one-pointedness of mind

Samadhi is similar to deep sleep state, which everyone experiences within sleep every night, the difference being self is aware of real self(soul) and not being a body in Samadhi, whereas deep sleep is born out of ignorance of unenlightened people in which self thinks that self donot exist during deep sleep.

Real meditation is thoughtless, meditation on form of God is just done for bringing never fulfilling thirst of senses from worldly distractions and making mind one pointedness which is also called [Pratyahara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratyahara).
Cessation of mind and its thoughts, itself is highest level of Yoga(union with Brahman), while Shiva being Adi Yogi, is Sagun form of that [Brahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman).

This is also explained in Shiva Purana

> Chapter 5 – Siva is with form and formless. Having both attributes,
>   Siva is worshipped in the Linga and the embodied form.

Formless aspect is also called Brahman in Vedas, and Brahman has no ego. It is Sat Chit Ananda, true blissful and ever-pervading.

Comment: I also downvote your answer. It is related to how man's mind limits God, and how the mind asks something it is never made to know for a human. Don't ask what Shiva thinks whan he meditate. What Bill Gates thinks when he has so much money. It is the God will, the Bill will, what he thinks. Not your problem. Start thinking about yourself. That can be good enough to don't even ask some question which answer is far far away from your limited mind.

Comment: The question is wrong in it's own phrase. No one from mankind can bring deads alive and no one can explain what is happening after physical death with the concept named soul. As nobody can do those things I think we shall focus on God as target, not as a subject we may judge. Since Vishnu for some, Shiva for others, Iisus for others, Allah for others is Supreme (and the only true) God.

Comment: @user3344236 I think your comments are better suited under the question. It seems like you do not want anyone to answer the question. Maybe you should write an answer yourself than writing so many comments, that way there is a better chance people will understand your perspective!! :)

Comment: @user3344236  i am sorry to interrupt u but even u knw that sanatan dharma gives us the power to reason...and u know that in meditation we are remembering god and his grace...with no contact to our surroundings...then there must be something god is thinking too...which i thought of finding...and sir by the way bill gates does call jesus christ..after all he is a human too and humans have god as their savior

Comment: I deleted my post and later undeleted it

Comment: what happened to my reputation