# Why does Lord Shiva meditate at all?

Tags: shiva, meditation

My question is different to :[Why do Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva always meditate on each other?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3191/why-do-lord-vishnu-and-lord-shiva-always-meditate-on-each-other)

I will divvy up my question into 2 as they are overlapping and somewhat relevant to each other.

1. I dont want to know why Gods meditate upon each other - but why does God have to meditate at all? Doesn't meditation pre-suppose the existence of a mind - which then suggests there is existence of an ego or the possibility of one.
2. I am trying to find out why Lord Shiva is shown to be meditating most of the times?
   Wouldn't meditation only at times mean that He identifies Himself with His body and ego?
   What does a God achieve by meditation? If Shiva is adi and anant what is His agenda with meditation?

Comment: Why does God walk instead of teleporting everywhere? It will confuse the hell out of everyone else, so he sticks to what a non-deity would be theoretically capable of doing for the vast majority of the time.

Comment: 1 & 2) to extend lifetime of reality and components

Comment: The very same reason you go to sleep every night. Gods meditate on Self because they dont have involuntary night sleep system.Meditating upon one another are Puranic stories to bring harmony between Shaivas, Vaishnava sects of Kaliyuga. Meditation is done on Atman which is non-dual bodyless than how can there be ego and differences in it. Now an animal or common human thinks it does not exist in deep sleep, but consciousness or atman experiences everything even in deep sleep and dreams, which gods and yogis control themselves & called meditation. Atman is immortal Self, read gita to understand