# Are Vishnu and Shiva the biggest devotees of each other?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, vaishnavism, shaivism

Are Vishnu and Shiva biggest devotees of each other? I read online that Shiva is the foremost Vaishnav and Vishnu is the foremost Shaiv, is this true? If yes please quote your source.

It would make sense since they are part the One Ultimate Reality.

Thank You!

Comment: Only if they are perceived as two separate human beings with extraordinary powers (like X-men) then the answer is yes. It can only be found in Bhakti Literature.

Comment: I think historically both Vishnu and Shiva came to be independently seen as Supreme Gods, and at some point of time, people realized there cannot be two Ishwaras, thus leading to various ways of reconciling the two Gods.

Comment: See this answer -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28667/4732