# Why does Brahma's Brahmastra destroy when his task is to create?

Tags: brahma, weapon, brahmastra

Lord Brahma is very well-known as the creator of the world. His task is concerned with creation.

Lord Brahma's weapon is named "Brahmastra", and its work is to destroy.

So when Lord Brahma is related to creation, why is his weapon related to destruction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the story behind 'Brahmasthra'? Is it actually fired ever?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2942/what-is-the-story-behind-brahmasthra-is-it-actually-fired-ever)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Nah, Its not duplicate, its related either. My question is purely resides in the last line.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of any weapon is to attack and/or destroy the enemy, so if you're just asking why Brahma uses weapons at all when he is supposed to be the creator god, it's because the gods are constantly fighting battles with the Asuras (demons).  Now if you're asking why the Brahmastra is so destructive compared to other Astras, Astras are related to the powers of the god they're associated with.  And since Brahma is the god of creation, the Brahmastra is able to destroy anything created by Brahma, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2945/36).

Comment: Brahma goes to sleep after creation work, then when he will get time to go for battle? when he will use Bramhastra ?

Comment: @Kedarnath Any fighting that Brahma does is during the Kalpa (the period when he's awake).  It's true that during the Kalpa Brahma is involved in creation work, but that doesn't mean he can never take a break from it if it becomes necessary to fight in a war.  This excerpt from the Vidyeshwara Samhita of the Shiva Purana describes an occasion where Brahma fights Vishnu: http://gdurl.com/G2pU (Note that this passage is probably an interpolation, like much of the Shiva Purana, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/267/36)