# Is it true that pre colonial Hinduism never taught that all religions are same?

Tags: identification-request, other-religions

A few days back, prominent Hindu rights activist,Shefali Vaidya [shared a post](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=10161362440177796&id=582727795) on her facebook feed. It had a message from Sri Dharma Pravartaka Acharya. Here it is-

> As I travel the nation delivering lectures on Hindu philosophy and spirituality, I frequently encounter a repeated scenario. Hindu parents will approach me after I’ve finished my lecture and timidly ask for advice. The often-repeated story goes somewhat like this: “We raised our daughter (or son) to be a good Hindu. We took her to the temple for important holidays. We even sent her to a Hindu camp for a weekend when she was 13. Now at the age of 23, our child has left Hinduism and converted to the (fill in the blank) religion. When we ask how she could have left the religion of her family, the answer she throws back in our face is: ‘Mama/dada, you always taught me that all religions are the same, and that it doesn’t really matter how a person worships God. So what does it matter if I have followed your advice and switched to another religion?’ “
>
> Historically, pre-colonial, classical Hinduism never taught that all
> religions are the same. This is not to say, however, that Hinduism has
> not believed in tolerance or freedom of religious thought and
> expression. It has always been a religion that has taught tolerance of
> other valid religious traditions. However, the assertion that a) we
> should have tolerance for the beliefs of other religions is a
> radically different claim from the overreaching declaration that b)
> all religions are the same. This confusion between two thoroughly
> separate assertions may be one reason why so many modern Hindus
> believe that Hindu tolerance is synonymous with Radical Universalism.
> To maintain a healthy tolerance of another person’s religion does not
> mean that we have to then adopt that person’s religion!
>
> If we want to ensure that our youth remain committed to Hinduism as a
> meaningful path, that our leaders teach Hinduism in a manner that
> represents the tradition faithfully and with dignity, and that the
> greater Hindu community can feel that they have a religion that they
> can truly take pride in, then we must abandon Radical Universalism. If
> we want Hinduism to survive so that it may continue to bring hope,
> meaning and enlightenment to untold future generations, then the next
> time our son or daughter asks us what Hinduism is really all about,
> let us not slavishly repeat to them that all religions are the same.
> Let us instead look into their eyes, and teach them the uniquely
> precious, beautifully endearing, and philosophically profound truths
> of our tradition–truths that have been responsible for keeping
> Hinduism a vibrantly living religious force for over 5,000 years. Let
> us teach them Sanatana Dharma, the eternal way of Truth
>
> ~ Sri Dharma Pravartaka Acharya

So is it true that pre colonial Hinduism had different attitude for other religions than compared to today's Hinduism which is sort of diluted with radical universalism promoted by some Hindu saints.

Comment: I have not come across any pre-colonial Hindu work that says all religions are the same. As is well-known, Adi Shankara and many other Acharyas, criticized Buddhism.

Comment: @zero exactly. I think "all relgions are same" concept was born in colonial bengal during reformation. With people like raja rammohun roy, ramakrishna and others spearheading this radical universalism.

Comment: This is not a forum to prove or disprove youtube, facebook, twitter, etc. postings. Your question should be directed to the author of the social media posting. If the person who holds the views stated, they should provide a source for their views. As it is stated it is a historical opinion.  See also https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9927/common-interpretation-of-shiva-purana-concerning-who-is-the-greatest-brahma-vi/10011#10011 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26901/who-is-considered-hindu/43192#43192

Comment: @RishX You need see the following answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13624

Comment: Not just pre-colonial. Even today, it is same. Vaishnavas do not accept Shaiva doctrine as means to Moksha, or Buddhist doctrine, or Parsi or Yahoodi & vice-versa. What it means is that all of them cannot simultaneously be the final ladder step before Moksha. We do accept that all of them are steps in the ladder though. We just do not accept the hierarchy. In other words, those who are born in Islam now, might take birth in Christianity next, then Jewish, then Jain, Buddh, finally Hinduism, and within Hindusim, followers of different deities, finally Vishnu devotees get Moksha.

Comment: It's like class1, class 2 .. class 12, getting promoted (or demoted) depending on your actions. That's what Hindus mean when we say all religions are paths to God. Not Direct paths, but steps in the path. We believe that Sanatan Dharma is the final step. Simply because it has answers to every question in life, that other religions can't (or don't) answer - basically, rebirth & karma.

Comment: So is the aacharya saying that only Sanatan Dharm leads to moksha?

Comment: @mar Your ‘model’  to moksha is that of a ladder,while there is another concept,that of many rivers,reaching the same ocean .The latter gives equal validity to any true religious tradition,as was also shown by Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa,when he “practised” different faiths,and experienced spiritual ‘fulfillment’ in them.(continued)

Comment: @mar (Continued) Sanatan Dharma,I feel,expounds about things that Abrahamaic faiths don’t (as you rightly pointed out).But the Abrahamaic faiths are (I feel) ,for people who are not inquisitive,and don’t tend to think independently;they are told to do something,they do it;no questions asked.It’s like Cerlac,while Sanatan Dharm is more like solid food.

Comment: @mar Whether they like easily digestible Cerlac,or Solid food which they like to dissect,fully taste,understand and then swallow,depends on their temperament; nonetheless, after the due course of Cerlac/Solid food is undergone,the nutrition that is eventual moksha will be attained.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda it's not just a historical question. I am interested how pre modern Hindu philosophers viewed other religions. If that is not related to this,I don't know what is.

Comment: @Rickross thank you so much. This pretty much solves my doubt. I used to think that jainism and buddhism being valid was just a RSS beleif with no scriptural validity

Comment: @mar your perception all "all religions are same" statement makes more sense. Sadly many Hindus believe the opposite. They think such statements makes exclusive abrahmic religions more valid for them. That's why so many conversion.

Comment: @Amethyst then why be a Hindu? According to radical universalism preached by ramakrishna, raja rammohan roy and other bengali "reformists", even exclusive paths like abrahamic religion are valid. This means abhramaic religions are true in the belief that only they reach to God, which according your belief, is even supported by Hinduism. Maybe that's why we see so many conversions from Hinduism.

Comment: @RishiX Because Hinduism ,as I said,is much more deep.Abrahamaic faiths only give simple,easy to glean commands to the followers,who don’t like to think much,there is not much scope for thought/debate.Mu belief is that Abrahamaic **spirituality,not religion** is as valid as Hinduism.In spirituality,one doesn’t mind as to what the other person believes or doesn’t believe.For a fact,preachers like Zakir Naik would probably have a hard time trying to explain the supernatural powers(continued...)

Comment: @RishiX (continued) that Siddhas in Sanatan Dharm have.I personally know/have heard of Muslims who have sought the help of Hindu siddhas when their relative got possessed;others who asked for wealth from Devi Parvati and duly received it.Likewise I know Christians who have obtained the help of such Siddhas.So the key point is that religion might fail,spirituality won’t

Comment: @Amethyst point is what do you mean by abrahamic spirituality? abrahamic religions lack spirituality to a great extant. What you said about muslims and christians worshipping Hindu deities, I don't know about that but I can claim that Hindus visit churches, mosques and dargahs the vice versa is almost never true. Since "idol worshipping" is a sin for them even though they worship idol(kaaba,jesus,mary).

Comment: @Amethyst also what you said about Ramakrishna tradition... that's not in line with Ramakrishna Vivekananda beliefs..what the other user said about religions being like classes(1st to 12th) is more close to Ramakrishna-Vivekananda belief. Even one rkm monk here said Vivekananda belived some religions are more true than others and even quoted his works.

Comment: @ “what do you mean by Abrahamaic spirituality” Depends on which faith is in question,I will try to list some aspects of Christianity in this regard,as far as I could gather.For Orthodox Christians,spirituality is a higher concept(appreciably seen in monks),since the faith(like its sister faiths),is majorly objective.Again,among Christians, Orthodox and Catholic spirituality is expressed in honouring theory saints and emulating them(especially Mother Mary),taming the flesh by fasting and denial,special hymns,etc.As for Protestants,their spirituality is mostly Bible centric,(continued)..

Comment: ..Bible centric ,and majorly involves singing and clapping(similar to sankirtan and bhajan),and the eventual descent of the Holy Spirit,which is characterised by “speaking in tongues”(similar to the ecstasy of a bhakt in bhajan).This may not be under the scope of this site,but I have tried to answer your question,since you asked it,hope this helps.

Comment: @RishiX “As the different streams having their sources in different paths which men take through different tendencies, various though they appear, crooked or straight, all lead to Thee.”
This was spoken by Swami Vivekananda in Chicago.From what I understand,Swamiji treats each path of spirituality,as independently valid.(Of course omitting the folly of “my way or the highway”)This link: https://belurmath.org/sri-ramakrishna/. also talks about how Sri Ramakrishna saw faiths as paths and not rungs in a ladder.There are also sayings by Swami Vivekanand,where he extols Christ as God.

Answer (score 1):

In a certain way, the Bhagavad Gita 4.11 seems to proclaim a sort of religous universalism:

> [Shankara Bhasya](https://archive.org/details/Bhagavad-Gita.with.the.Commentary.of.Sri.Shankaracharya/page/n137/mode/2up)
> 4.11 “Howsoever men approach Me, even so do I reward them; My path do men follow in all things O son of Pritha”
>
> Commentary: “[...] In all things, men follow My path, the path of the Isvara who exists in all forms. [Here ‘men’ stands for all those who are engaged in works precscribed according to their respective ends]”

Even the Vaishnava commentaries acknowledge this:

> [Vaishnava commentary: Sārārtha-Varṣiṇī Prakāśikā-vṛtti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shrimad-bhagavad-gita/d/doc419867.html)
> “According to their degree of conviction, I cast some of them into the cycle of birth and death. I appear as void to the nihilists, or śūnyavādīs, merging their existence with the void. I completely cover the consciousness of the materialistic empiricists, as well as those who identify themselves as being born of nature, by making their consciousness almost inert. I am only attainable to them in the form of inert nature. I appear as Īśvara to the yogīs, rewarding them with mystic powers or impersonal liberation. **In this way, as the intrinsic form of everything (sarva-svarūpa), I am the object of achievement for all types of beliefs.** Among them all, the only one that should be considered supreme is attainment of transcendental service to Me. All human beings follow one of My various paths.”

Comment: Please see if you are able to post the Sanskrit commentary.